# Japan software export statistics

Tags: data-request, finance, software, japan

How much in pre-packaged software does Japan export yearly?

I have found these statistics in [an OCDE report](http://www.oecd.org/internet/ieconomy/2094340.pdf) (table 7), unfortunately they are old, and limited to the USA:

```
1990: 4.1 million US$
1991: 16.0 million US$
1992: 9.7 million US$
1993: 7.1 million US$
1994: 6.0 million US$
1995: 5.4 million US$
1996: 4.2 million US$
```

Are there more up-to-date statistics, for Japan export to the whole world?

Wikipedia has [Japan export data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Japan_Export_Treemap.jpg) but it does not seem to include software:

[image: Japan export data]

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of how Japan handles exports but the US Dept of Commerce Bureau of Industry and Security (BIS) has a list of [10 Commerce Control List Categories and  these are broken into 5 Product Groups](http://www.bis.doc.gov/index.php/licensing/commerce-control-list-classification/commerce-control-list-ccl/17-regulations/139-commerce-control-list-ccl)

It looks like software is a Product Group and this means it would need to be aggregated across categories.

The staff at BIS may be your best bet on connecting with someone that can lead to the data.

If you find out anything, please post back here.

Comment: Do you mean they might have someone who knows about Japan data?

Comment: I would assume they are aware of their counterparts in other countries.  If not by name, then by agency.